# how to add onchange event to ul tag elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down with set of 'ul' and 'li' like this,

```
<div style="float:left;">
    <div class="group">
        <div style="width:80px;">Dropdown<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></div>
            <ul style="float:left;">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Option1</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Option2</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Option3</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add onchange() event to ul tag. I can say onchange i have to call one function SelectedItem(optionselected) with selected 'li' text as parameter.Anyone Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: change will only trigger on form elements that have a value, see http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Use onclick in UL lis or links

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The `change event` is sent to an element when its value changes. This
>   event is limited to  elements, `<textarea>` boxes and
>   `<select>` elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons,
>   the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with
>   the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until
>   the element loses focus.

see http://api.jquery.com/change/

So `.change()` doesn't work on an unordered list...

Use `click` event for it

```
    $('li').click(function(){
     //your code
 });
```